# persistenceEnabled works in simulator, but raise a NSInternalInconsistencyException on device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I've enable Firebase's disk persistence in my app by setting persistenceEnable to true

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    return true
}
```

When I run the app in xcode's iPhone simulator everything work as expected but when I run the app on the device I get an NSInternalInconsistencyException.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unrecognized database version: '

*** First throw call stack:

(0x18e68d1b8 0x18d0c455c 0x18e68d100 0x10014323c 0x100143124 0x100154434 0x100de9258 0x100de9218 0x100df6aec 0x100decce0 0x100df7088 0x100df8e2c 0x100df8b78 0x18d71f2a0 0x18d71ed8c)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don't really know what's happening. It looks like the exception is thrown when attaching an 'observe' listener

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 ref.child("usersEvents").child(userID!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
...
```

If I comment the persistenceEnabled = true

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()
    //FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    return true
}
```

The app works on my device but of course I loose the offline capabilities.

I've also tried to move the `FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true` but each time I use it the app crashed when executing on the iPhone.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**
I remove the app from my device and let xCode install a fresh copy of it and that solved the issue.

**Full comment :**
After some trying to reproduce the issue in an other project for several hours without success I found the solution.

The error message is not 100% clear but gives a good clue `Unrecognized database version:`

As the app was only crashing on my device when `persistenceEnabled` was set to `true` I figured out the issue must have been related to the local database cache.

I remove the app from my device and let xCode install a fresh copy of it and that solved the issue.

Somehow the local Firebase cache must have been corrupted and each time Firebase's sdk tried to access it my app crashed.

I hope this may help someone facing the same issue some days.